# GridView fill column widths

Tags: android, gridview

Consider the following:

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="15dp"
    android:paddingEnd="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_Progress_Level"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:text="@string/Progress"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb_Assignment_Progress"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"/>

</GridLayout>
```

In the above GridLayout, my ProgressBar has been set to 50% for the sake of width testing.

However, with the above setup, this is the result: 
[image]

The bar is clearly **NOT** on the 50% mark.

Yes this is because I've used fill parent that actually takes up the space from the start of grid till the end of it.

I have tried using `wrap_content` on the bar, but it seems a lot shorter:
[image]

Is there a way I can fill up the remaining space of the grid?

Isn't `fill_parent` suppose to mean to fill up the remaining space? Guess I was wrong. It is actually a deprecated version of `match_parent`

I don't want the bar to possess the width of the grid, instead I want it to just fill up the remaining space after the `TextView`

Comment: I tried match_parent but it actually possesses the width of the whole gridview and then presents in the 2nd column which I don't want it to be. I want it to only take up the column space.

Comment: A cell? How is that implemented in my gridlayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as changing the following:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

TO

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

and add the following:

```
android:layout_gravity="fill"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
 <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="15dp"
    android:paddingStart="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_Progress_Level"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Progress"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pb_Assignment_Progress"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>


</GridLayout>
```

Happy coding!!